# Printing JSON object in JSP

Tags: json, jsp

I have a servlet which creates a JsonObject.

```
JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "john");
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "Smith");
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "Ram");

HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("jsonObject", jsonObject);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("viewpage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

And this is my JSP page

```
<%@page import="com.google.gson.JsonObject"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>View Json</title>
<%
JsonObject jsonObject=(JsonObject)session.getAttribute("jsonObject");
%>

</head>
<body>
<h6>JSON View</h6>
<br>
<%=jsonObject%>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i run this, the JSP file printing only the last data. The following is the output

```
JSON View


{"name":"Ram"}
```

How can i print the whole? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "john");
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "Smith");
jsonObject.addProperty("name", "Ram");
```

Here you used same key as "name".So the values are overriding.Try to use different names like

```
jsonObject.addProperty("name1", "john");
jsonObject.addProperty("name2", "Smith");
jsonObject.addProperty("name3", "Ram");
```

Comment: @Shiju K Babu did you understand the problem

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But what if i want to add many names as inner arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating JsonArray.
Like this

```
    JsonArray arr = new JsonArray() ;
JsonObject obj1 = new JsonObject()
obj1 .addProperty("name", "john");

JsonObject obj2 = new JsonObject()
obj2 .addProperty("name", "smith");

JsonObject obj3 = new JsonObject()
obj3 .addProperty("name", "ram");

arr.add(obj1);
arr.add(obj2);
arr.add(obj3);
```